# Java android multi serial ports

Tags: java, android, serial-port

Hi I have a problem I have a device which have a multi serial ports , How I can connect and read data from two Serial Ports ?

I try use this library :implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
And in this library is example multiple ports
https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/blob/master/examplemultipleports/src/main/java/com/felhr/examplemultipleports/UsbService.java

But when I try start this service my application crashed

i want to read from android device data from two rs , how I can do it ?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more concrete information about the problem and what you tried to fix it.